# Adding an object to an arraylist causes the object's fields to become null

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I have this code:

```
    blocks.clear();
    if(onStart.parts==null){System.out.println("null before");}
    blocks.add(onStart);
    if(blocks.get(0).parts==null){System.out.println("null after");}
```

where blocks is an initialized `ArrayList<Block>`, and parts is a field of Block of type `ArrayList<BlockPart>`. For some reason, that snippet of code only outputs "`null after`". Why does the parts field become null?

EDIT: I have added the following code:

```
    System.out.println(blocks.get(0)==onStart?"same":"not same");
    System.out.println(blocks.get(0).parts==onStart.parts?"same":"not same");
```

The output is now:

```
same
not same
```

Strangely, the `null after` isn't showing in the console anymore.

EDIT 2: Replacing parts with name causes only `null after` to show. I don't know why the issue with the parts field somehow fixed itself. Before, I made the parts field final, but then removed the final modifier from it because I thought that I might want to change .parts later on. Now, it fixed itself. IDK why.

Comment: Is it the same Object? You can test with System.out.println("Are the same? " + onStart==blocks.get(0));

Comment: `System.out.println(blocks.get(0)==onStart?"same":"not same");` outputs "`same`".

Comment: Can you post up the Block class too? Do you have any code that sets parts to null? If yes put a break point in there and run your debugger to see how it gets there.

Comment: I have no code that would set it to null. Just some fields, a method and a constructor. I'm going to try making parts final.

Comment: Does it also happen to print "null before"? Can you post the full output of the program?

Comment: I made it final, and that works as a workaround.

Comment: It doesn't print null before.

Comment: Was it initialised by a different thread from which it is accessed? (i.e. could it be a thread visibility issue?)

Comment: There are no other threads.

Comment: Is `onStart` Block or a subclass of Block?

Comment: Please, show all the code (or at least, a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

Your final statement:

```
System.out.println(blocks.get(0)==onStart?"same":"not same");
System.out.println(blocks.get(0).parts==onStart.parts?"same":"not same");
```

implies that it's something in your syntax that is changing the way your objects are being accessed.  Break the second one down:

```
Block newblock=blocks.get(0)
```

then if newblock == onStart, newblock.parts MUST == onStart.parts

if that proves out then you can delve in to examining why the syntax doesn't chain together well.

Comment: I replaced `System.out.println(blocks.get(0).parts==onStart.parts?"same":"not same");` with `Block newBlock=blocks.get(0);System.out.println(newBlock==onStart);System.out.println(newBlock.parts==onStart.parts);` and got true, then false.

Comment: if newBlock == onStart then they are aliases for the same object.  newBlock.parts IS onstart.parts.  does onStart.parts == onStart.parts??? Being a pointer compare this doesn't even invoke .equals or any getters so there is no room for shenanigans there.  Any chance you are using Groovy, Spring or something else funny? This could happen in a language with property support, but I just can't see how it could happen in java.

Comment: No libraries, no other threads. I would post a complete SSCCE if I could, but I can't recreate it for some reason. I came to stackoverflow for suggestions on what might be causing the problem. BTW, onstart.parts==onstart.parts returns true. I'm going to work on trying to get a SSCCE that reproduces this without including all 22 classes.

Comment: Any inheritance going on?  Specifically does block extend another class or is block extended by another class where both have "parts" members?

Comment: Block is an abstract class, OnStart is a subclass.

Comment: Do they both define "parts"?

Comment: Yes. Block defines it this way, at the top of the class: `public ArrayList<BlockPart> parts=new ArrayList<>();`, and OOOOH I redefined parts again at the top of OnStart, forgot to initialize that, default is null! Removed that line, working perfectly! Thanks!